# How to read a specific value in a .txt file, and then compare it with another?

Tags: c

actually i'm new at programming and stuff, and I want to create some sort of programm, where I put in some data, then it prints it to a .txt file. (DONE!), so now I want to read the file, and get existing values of weight in the file. and compare the existing value with the new value, and make a difference out of it. (for example: lost weight: 0.2kg, or anything like that).

actually thats how i create the data

```
FILE *f;
f = fopen("weight.txt", "a");
fprintf(f, "\nDate: %02i.%02i.%4i\nTime: %02i:%02i Uhr\nWeight: %0.2f\n", data.day, data.month, data.year, data.hour, data.minute, data.weight);
fclose(f);
```

now i want to get weight out of this file and compare it to the new one. I've no idea how to handle this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read about `fscanf`?

Comment: @prashantpiyush havent tried anything so far, I ve no idea how to read out weight: only, without date or time. Don't know where I should start im sry

Comment: Start by reading about `fscanf` it is similar to `scanf` but reads from a file. Try to read every value present in your file and then discard the ones you don't need.

Comment: tried it out. used fseek to get to start of the file. created 2 chars with array  of 16 . after fseek i tried to use fscanf with the new strings, but no really useful output. instead my file got completely over written instead of attached now. so back to the beginning, how to use fscanf then properly to read a value out, im totally new i may not see this as technically correct as you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can read about how `fscanf` works [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanf-and-fscanf-in-c-simple-yet-poweful/) and about `fgets` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fgets-gets-c-language/)

```
FILE f = fopen("weight.txt", "r");
char buf[100];     // buffer string
float weight;      // variable to hold the input weight

// read the first three lines
fgets(buf, 100, f);
fgets(buf, 100, f);
fgets(buf, 100, f);

// read the last line using fscanf and
// store the weight read
fscanf(f, "Weight: %f\n", &weight);

fclose(f);

printf("Weigth: %f\n", weight);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to write the file, you used the FILE type and the some of the builtins `file I/O` C functions.

Have you tried to search what are the others builtin C function which can be used in order to handle files?

Comment: hi yes, I know there exists fread and fwrite. fread seems to read a file. but I dont know how to use it as correctly as it only gets me the value of an existing weight input out.